# jquery last() method not working properly for appended table row

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

I append row to table using jquery. I want to access only the last appended row element, and set data-i="" attribute of that specific row.

Whether I write `last()` or `:first`, or `:first-child` or `last-child` in the below statement, always selects the bottom row of the table.

Also, it removes every rows data-i="" attributes values in the table; except for the bottom tr.

Also cannot set data-i="" attr if there is only one row..

```
function readURL(input) {    
    var el;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
        if (input.files[i]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                el = '<tr><td><span><img src="' + e.target.result + '"/></span></td><td><input type="button" value="Cancel" data-i=""/></td></tr>';
                $('table#uploadfiles tbody').after(el);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            imageList.push(input.files[i]);
            if (imageList.length > 1) {                   
                $("tr", "table#uploadfiles").filter(':last').find('input[value="Cancel"]').attr("data-i", imageList.length);
                //el.find('input[value="Cancel"]').attr("data-i", imageList.length);
            }
            else {                    
                //$this.find('input[value="Kapat"]').attr("data-i", imageList.length);
                $('table#uploadfiles > tbody > tr > td').find('input[value="Cancel"]').attr("data-i", "1");
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

So, `last()` , `:first`, `:first-child` ,`last-child`,`.filter(':last')` are not working for manually appended table rows.. Why it is not working?

Comment: can you add demo code with html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want appended rows with increased index (top's index = 1, bottom's index will be 2, 3 ,4 ,5, 6 .....N)

Your original solution has a bug: `onload` event and following `imageList` codes are **asynchronous**. We can't control which one will be first finished.

So I modify your code to a simple solution:

1. Change `imageList` to a object(dictionary).
2. Current `input.files[i]` stored in `render.inputfile`
3. Create a global index `fileIndex` to control the `data-i="fileIndex"`
4. In `onload` function, store current `inputfile` mapping to `fileIndex` in `imageList` and `fileIndex` increases.
5. When you click on Cancel button, you can get index from `data-i` and access the original `input.file` by `imageList[index]`

My sample code:

[Append row to table with increased index](https://jsfiddle.net/08aLvdps/)

Comment: 'imageList' and table row data-i indexes must be equivalent here; I append the last inserted image index thats why 'imageList' is important. So when cancel button clicked, i will remove the equivalent imageList item and the row